# Which tuning should be used for Gymnopedie 1 on steel string guitar

Tags: acoustic-guitar, alternative-tunings

I am trying to tune my steel string acoustic to sound like the interpretation performed by Brandon J. Acker, although his guitar is gut strung. I tried E major and D major but it doesn't sound like his for some reason, can someone tell me which tuning should be used. The original version for piano was written in E major key.

Link to the performance.

Comment: Can't you tell just by looking at his fingers? Looks like standard tuning to me, you can tell in the first 2 chords.

Comment: Yes I am playing on standard, never played on gut strung guitars, and on some music sheets it's D major, so confused

Comment: You're watching his hands whilst listening to the notes played. Match one to the other & you'll quickly see it's standard tuning. Some other arrangement in another key is irrelevant.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a misperception, that a nonstandard tuning is required.

Comment: I would vote for not closing because there is a simple answer: "It's in standard tuning and it sounds different because it's a classical guitar, different player and whatever signal processing that the system used for recording it, Youtube and the system you're watching it on do."